# pdf-lib: Not able to draw text in a scanned pdf

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, async-await

I'm trying to draw text in a rectangle a pdf using the pdf-lib library. It is possible for pdf files that are not scanned. See below screenshot:

[image: Text in rectangle - normal pdf file]

It doesn't work for scanned pdf files. Basically it's the `modifyPdf` function that does the job. We read the pdf file and then draw the rectangle and text. Then we encode it using base64 and set it as the iframe source. Please see below code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['fname']))
{
    $fname = trim($_GET['fname']);
    $fname_array = explode('/', $fname);
    $label_str = end($fname_array);
    $label_str = addslashes($label_str);
}
else
    die('Access denied');
?>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>PDF Viewer</title>
</head>

<body></body>

 <!--<script src="js/pdf-lib.min.js"></script>-->
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/pdf-lib@1.11.1/dist/pdf-lib.js"></script>


<!-- <script src="https://unpkg.com/pdf-lib@1.4.0"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/downloadjs@1.4.7"></script> -->

<script>

    (async () => {


    //const { degrees, PDFDocument, rgb, StandardFonts } = PDFLib

    let FinalModifiedFilesToBeUploaded = await modifyPdf('<?=$label_str?>', 13, '<?=$fname?>')

    for (let i = 0; i < FinalModifiedFilesToBeUploaded.length; i++) {
        let iframeSrc = FinalModifiedFilesToBeUploaded[i]
        let iframe = document.createElement('iframe')
        iframe.setAttribute('style', 'width: 100%; height: 100%;')
        iframe.setAttribute('src', iframeSrc)
        iframe.setAttribute('class', 'custom-pdf-frame')
        document.body.appendChild(iframe)
    }

    async function modifyPdf(text, textSize, path ) {
        let MODIFIED_FILES = []
      // Fetch an existing PDF document
      /*const url = 'https://pdf-lib.js.org/assets/with_update_sections.pdf'*/
      const url = path
        const existingPdfBytes = await fetch(url).then(res => res.arrayBuffer())

      const pdfDoc = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.load(existingPdfBytes)
                        const helveticaFont = await pdfDoc.embedFont(PDFLib.StandardFonts.Helvetica)
                        const textWidth = helveticaFont.widthOfTextAtSize(text, textSize);
                        // const textHeight = helveticaFont.heightAtSize(textSize);
                        const pages = pdfDoc.getPages()
                        const firstPage = pages[0]
                        console.log(firstPage)
                        if (firstPage) {
                            const {
                                width,
                                height
                            } = firstPage.getSize()
                            try{
                            console.log(firstPage.drawText(text, {
                                x: width / 2 - textWidth / 2,
                                y: height / 2 + 367,
                                size: textSize,
                                font: helveticaFont,
                                opacity: 1,
                                //color: PDFLib.rgb(0.13333333333333333, 0.5450980392156862, 0.13333333333333333),
                            }))
                            }
                            catch(err) {
  alert('test1'+err)
}
try{
                            firstPage.drawRectangle({
                                x: width / 2 - textWidth / 2 - 10,
                                y: height / 2 + 357,
                                width: textWidth + 20,
                                height: 30,
                                borderWidth: 1,
                                //color: PDFLib.rgb(1, 1, 0),
                                opacity: 0.2,
                            })
}
catch(err) {
  alert('test2'+err)
}
                            const pdfDataUri = await pdfDoc.saveAsBase64({
                                dataUri: true
                            });
                            MODIFIED_FILES.push(pdfDataUri)
                        } else {
                            alert('Page not found')
                        }
console.log(MODIFIED_FILES)
                        return MODIFIED_FILES

            // Trigger the browser to download the PDF document
      //download(pdfBytes, "pdf-lib_modification_example.pdf", "application/pdf");
    }
    })()
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found out the answer. I identified that for scanned files the text was indeed getting printed but on areas out of the scope of display. This was because the width of the document was greater than the height. So I fixed it using the following code:

```
if(width > height)
                            {
                                try{
                            firstPage.drawText(text, {
                                x: height+150,
                                y: width-430,
                                size: textSize,
                                font: helveticaFont,
                                opacity: 1,
                                color: PDFLib.rgb(0.13333333333333333, 0.5450980392156862, 0.13333333333333333),
                                rotate: PDFLib.degrees(-90),
                            })
                            }
                            catch(err) {
}
try{
                            firstPage.drawRectangle({
                                x: height+140,
                                y: width-420,
                                width: textWidth + 20,
                                height: 30,
                                borderWidth: 1,
                                color: PDFLib.rgb(1, 1, 0),
                                opacity: 0.2,
                                rotate: PDFLib.degrees(-90),
                            })
}
catch(err) {
}
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                firstPage.drawText(text, {
                                x: width / 2 - textWidth / 2,
                                y: height / 2 + 367,
                                size: textSize,
                                font: helveticaFont,
                                opacity: 1,
                                color: PDFLib.rgb(0.13333333333333333, 0.5450980392156862, 0.13333333333333333),
                            })
                            firstPage.drawRectangle({
                                x: width / 2 - textWidth / 2 - 10,
                                y: height / 2 + 357,
                                width: textWidth + 20,
                                height: 30,
                                borderWidth: 1,
                                color: PDFLib.rgb(1, 1, 0),
                                opacity: 0.2,
                            })
                            }
```